# Error when installing @binssoft/ngx-captcha in angular

Tags: angular, captcha

I try run this command in terminal:

npm install @binssoft/ngx-captcha --save

I got errors:

[image]

can someone help me

I try to run in terminal:

npm install @binssoft/ngx-captcha --save

and i used npm install and npm i and not working.

Answer (score 0):

use this command **npm install **@binssoft/ngx-captcha --force****

Comment: Welcome to SO! As it is currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit it and add more details why and how it works. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.